# DKMS Problem - dpkg error processing package linux-headers-generic

Tags: package-management, kernel, updates, dpkg, dkms

```
$ sudo apt full-upgrade
 [sudo] password for pepp: 
 Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-6.5.0-14 linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic
  linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic linux-modules-6.5.0-14-generic
  linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-14-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic linux-libc-dev
4 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 180 MB of archives.
After this operation, 273 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-6.5.0-14-generic amd64 6.5.0-14.14 [37,8 MB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/main amd64 linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic amd64 6.5.0-14.14 [14,0 MB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-14-generic amd64 6.5.0-14.14 [109 MB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/main amd64 linux-generic amd64 6.5.0.14.16 [1.704 B]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/main amd64 linux-image-generic amd64 6.5.0.14.16 [9.026 B]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-6.5.0-14 all 6.5.0-14.14 [13,4 MB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic amd64 6.5.0-14.14 [3.761 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-generic amd64 6.5.0.14.16 [8.880 B]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 6.5.0-14.14 [1.566 kB]
Fetched 180 MB in 60s (2.975 kB/s)                                             
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-6.5.0-14-generic.
(Reading database ... 341680 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-linux-modules-6.5.0-14-generic_6.5.0-14.14_amd64.deb .
..
Unpacking linux-modules-6.5.0-14-generic (6.5.0-14.14) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../1-linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic_6.5.0-14.14_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic (6.5.0-14.14) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-14-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../2-linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-14-generic_6.5.0-14.14_amd64
.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-14-generic (6.5.0-14.14) ...
Preparing to unpack .../3-linux-generic_6.5.0.14.16_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-generic (6.5.0.14.16) over (6.5.0.13.15) ...
Preparing to unpack .../4-linux-image-generic_6.5.0.14.16_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-generic (6.5.0.14.16) over (6.5.0.13.15) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-6.5.0-14.
Preparing to unpack .../5-linux-headers-6.5.0-14_6.5.0-14.14_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-6.5.0-14 (6.5.0-14.14) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../6-linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic_6.5.0-14.14_amd64.deb .
..
Unpacking linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic (6.5.0-14.14) ...
Preparing to unpack .../7-linux-headers-generic_6.5.0.14.16_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-generic (6.5.0.14.16) over (6.5.0.13.15) ...
Preparing to unpack .../8-linux-libc-dev_6.5.0-14.14_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-libc-dev:amd64 (6.5.0-14.14) over (6.5.0-13.13) ...
Setting up linux-modules-6.5.0-14-generic (6.5.0-14.14) ...
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (6.5.0-14.14) ...
Setting up linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic (6.5.0-14.14) ...
I: /boot/vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to vmlinuz-6.5.0-13-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img.old is now a symlink to initrd.img-6.5.0-13-generic
I: /boot/vmlinuz is now a symlink to vmlinuz-6.5.0-14-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img is now a symlink to initrd.img-6.5.0-14-generic
Setting up linux-headers-6.5.0-14 (6.5.0-14.14) ...
Setting up linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-14-generic (6.5.0-14.14) ...
Setting up linux-image-generic (6.5.0.14.16) ...
Setting up linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic (6.5.0-14.14) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.5.0-14-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' KVER=6.5.0-14-generic src=/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.8.7.1.....................
.........................(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl88x2bu: 5.8.7.1 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-14-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.8.7.1/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.5.0-14-generic/x86_64 failed for rtl88x2bu(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.5.0-14-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic package post-installation script subpr
ocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro
r from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message ind
icates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    dpkg: dependency problems pr
event configuration of linux-headers-generic:
 linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 6.5.0.14.16); however:
  Package linux-headers-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic (6.5.0-14.14) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.5.0-14-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' KVER=6.5.0-14-generic src=/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.8.7.1.....................
.........................(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl88x2bu: 5.8.7.1 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-14-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.8.7.1/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.5.0-14-generic/x86_64 failed for rtl88x2bu(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.5.0-14-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic package post-installation script subproc
ess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encoun
tered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please can you add `dkms status` and `uname -r` to your question [edit].

Comment: dkms status: 
rtl88x2bu/5.8.7.1, 5.13.0-39-generic, x86_64: built
***********************
uname -r: 
6.5.0-13-generic

Comment: This is only first aid. In `/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.8.7.1/dkms.conf` look for string `AUTOINSTALL="yes"` and change it to ´AUTOINSTALL="no"` then remove the module from dkmstree `sudo dkms remove rtl88x2bu/5.8.7.1 --all` Make sure you have space in /boot `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: TYVM! NOW:
sudo apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libegl-mesa0 libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa libglx-mesa0
  libxatracker2 mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.

Comment: I think is because of phased Update please search for this i'm in mobile.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Nobody!